# Load External JSON once, use it repeatedly....?

Tags: jquery, ajax, scope

When my page loads, I want to immediately pull in JSON data from another server using $.ajax(), and I want to be able to access all the data without having to re-request the json file. The problem is, when I assign the data to a variable, the scope of that variable is confined to the $.ajax() function and I can't access it elsewhere...

It seems like since I have already loaded that information, I should be able to use it as many times as I need too without having to re-request it over and over again (slow). Using simple reddit.json request for example below

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/.json',
        timeout:3000,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var myData = data;  //this variable is confined :(
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

If I run it *outside* of the document.ready(), then I can get to it globally, but I didn't know if that was cool or not, or like *best practices*, you know...

Whats the **best** way to access an already-loaded json object outside of the scope of the function that made it's initial request? Or is it even possible...?

Comment: As long as you can guarantee that the data is only accessed *after* the Ajax request completes, you can store it wherever you want. E.g. if you need to access the data in event handlers, bind the event handlers only *after* the request completes.

Comment: If you use a global variable the JSON data can be shared with any caller, intended or not.

Comment: Related: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220321)

Comment: Thanks for the related link @FelixKling, looks like callbacks are the way to go. I think defining the variable globally will be enough to get me up-and-running for now, but I have some reading to do as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any one of the two options given below.

1.Declare a global variable before $(document).ready() function.Then use it inside like below.

```
<script>
var myData;
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://www.reddit.com/.json',
    timeout:3000,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        myData = data;  //this variable is confined :(
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

2.Place your data in HTML5 session storage or local storage depending on your requirement.Like below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://www.reddit.com/.json',
    timeout:3000,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        sessionStorage.myData=data;  //setting variable in session storage
        console.log(sessionStorage.myData); // getting variable from ss
        // for local storage replace sessionStorage with localStorage in above two lines
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('error');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This got my project up and running, but check out the linked post @FelixKling dropped up under my initial question... really good info there. 
I used method 1 btw...

Answer (score 0):

Load everything with ajax and then you can write it to file or put it in an global array which can be accessed from everywhere